# error in executing python code from notepad++ and an OpenCV function

Tags: python, opencv, notepad++

This is a simple piece of code that executes with no problems from the command line (Python Anaconda 3.5):

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
a=image.shape[0]
b=image.shape[1]
print("image size " + str(a) + " by " + str(b))
```

When it runs, you get the expected:

```
image size 3254 by 4928
```

However, when running from notepad++ 7.8.1, Windows 7), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    a=image.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++>
```

This seems odd.  The shortcut for python in Notepad++ is located in 
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ , in 'shortcuts.xml'.  This is:

```
 <Command name="python_35" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /K python &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

Any thoughts on why this might not be working?  If I type 'cmd /K python', I do get the Anaconda version of python (I was wondering if I was seeing another version of python on my system).  This doesn't fail on reading the image, so I'm thinking OpenCV is still being loaded.

Comment: Use the full image path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running File from Notepad Plus Plus and Current Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192941/running-file-from-notepad-plus-plus-and-current-directory)

Comment: If it solved your issue, you can post an answer to your own question, or delete it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

This question seems to solve the problem:

[Running File from Notepad Plus Plus and Current Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192941/running-file-from-notepad-plus-plus-and-current-directory)

cmd /k cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && python $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)

The confusing issue was the the error was caused by trying to access image.shape[0].  If the image isn't there, no error occurs on imread; i.e. image=cv2.imread('imagexyz.jpg'), but it will happen when you try to access 'image'.  Should check to see the image is there first, i.e.:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image_not_there.jpg')
if(image is None):
    print("no image")
else:
    a=image.shape[0]
    b=image.shape[1]
    print("image size " + str(a) + " by " + str(b))
```