# Is there any way to use notepad++ run command to execute it from current directory?

Tags: notepad++

When using Notepad++, i used run.. command to run a .bat file in a folder but when i am running it, the bat file goes to notepad++ directory and then runs itself.
'''C:/Program Files/Notepad++'''
Is There Any way so that i can run it from current directory where it is saved.
Update 1:I Created A Batch File That Inspects all java Files present in the folder where the batch file is kept And Compiles Them, it uses %cd% as locating the folder so when i want it to run from notepad++ v7.8.4. It Takse that batch file and keeps it in C:/Program Files/Notepad++   and then runs the batch file but i want notepad ++ to run it from the current directory where i have kept the batch file.
run in notepad++ can be opened by pressing F5.
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running File from Notepad Plus Plus and Current Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192941/running-file-from-notepad-plus-plus-and-current-directory)

Comment: no, I tried it earlier, it did not work in npp v.7.8.4.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you have tried, what version of Notepad++ you are using, what happened when you tried the suggested duplicate, and any other related information.

Comment: Sir,You are Misunderstanding Me. the Problem Here Is I Have Edited Shortcts.xml File Many Times But It Doesn't Come In Menu=> Run.

Comment: The updated question is very difficult to understand. Capitalising the first letter of (almost) every word also makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, @AdrianHHH I Got It , the problem was i was editing the wrong xml file. the file which was responsible was is%APPDATA%/Roaming/Notepad++/shortcuts.xml. There is the exact copy of shortcuts.xml which works fine.

```html
<Command name="CD and run file" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /C &quot;cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) &amp;&amp; $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

Sir Can You Please Edit The Above Code SO I Can Run My Executor Java.bat from It.
Thanks
Assuming my Bat File IS In :D:\Projects\Java\Java Executor

Comment: Is this an answer to your original question? Or, is it a new question? Please read the [help] pages for this site where it clearly states the distinction between answers and questions.

Comment: As Per your request i have made another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261732/notepad-run-a-batch-file-from-current-directory .