# Run a batch file from its parent directory in NotePad++

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I made a batch file that identifies java files kept in that particular folder and compiles them. But when I was running it from notepad++, the batch file was going to notepad++ working directory i.e. `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`, and then starting, so I was not getting desired output.

```
<Command name="Java_Executor" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">&quot;D:\Projects\Java\Executor Java.bat&quot;</Command>
```

I tried to edit it many times but didn't got desired output.

```
<Command name="second try" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /C &quot;cd /d D:\Projects\Java\ &amp;&amp; D:\Projects\Java\Executor Java.bat&quot;</Command>
```

This was my second try.

This is the third try:

```
<Command name="Java_Executor" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /k cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) &amp;&amp; &quot;D:\Projects\Java\Executor_Java.bat&quot;</Command>
```

What should I edit so that my batch file runs from the same folder where it is located?
Assuming my bat file is `D:\Projects\Java\Executor Java.bat` with the contents of:

```
@ECHO OFF
color F0
ECHO                                        WELCOME TO EXECUTOR
ECHO                                                         -Garvit Joshi(garvitjoshi9@gmail.com)
ECHO                                                          USER:%USERNAME%
cd %cd% 
:first
ECHO LOOKING FOR FILES IN:%cd%
color F0
ECHO Name Of Java Executable Files Present In Folder Are:
python Filename_java.py
set /p "input=Enter The File You Want To Execute:"
ECHO ===============================
javac %input%.java
ECHO ===============================
ECHO Name Of Java Executable Class Present In Folder Are:
python Filename_class.py
ECHO ===============================
javac %input%.java
ECHO ===============================
set /p "input=Enter The Class You Want To Run:"
color 0A
ECHO ===============================
ECHO OUTPUT:
ECHO ===============================
java %input%
ECHO ===============================
color 0F
pause
ECHO =======================================================
ECHO *******************************************************
ECHO =======================================================
goto first
```

Comment: Use the appropriate expansion of the batch file's special `%0` variable. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `call /?` to see those available. Then change the directory using either `CD`, `PushD` or `Start`'s `/D` option.

Comment: You appear to have a space in the filename `Executor Java.bat`. Spaces in filenames frequently cause problems. I suggest renaming the file.

Comment: did it, still not working

Comment: Can you explain to us what code that is you are using because that is not a batch file.  Looks like you are launching the batch file from some other language which isn't a Notepad++ problem.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/garvit-joshi/Java_Executor/blob/master/Executor%20Java.bat

Comment: @GarvitJoshi, I added your batch-file code from the link into the question post if that is OK, as my answer briefly references the batch-file code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Command name="Java Executor" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /k cd /d &quot;$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)&quot; &amp;&amp; &quot;D:\Projects\Java\Executor Java.bat&quot;</Command>
```

Third try seems almost there. You are changing directory from `'C:/Program Files/Notepad++` to `D:\Projects\Java` which will require `/d` after `cd`, else it will not change directory as to being on a different drive. Probably a good idea to enclose `$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` with double quotes as the current directory may have special characters with it's path i.e. `"D:\dogs & cats"`. `Executor Java.bat` displays same issues with use of `cd` so it will behave similar.

Test script `"D:\Projects\Java\Executor Java.bat"` being:

```
@echo cd: "%cd%"
```

Run `Java Executor` from Run menu of Notepad++ displays prompt window with:

> ```
> cd: "D:\Projects\Java"
>
> D:\Projects\Java>
> ```

The prompt is ready for input as `cmd /k` was used.

In the batch-file in the question post is the line:

> ```
> cd %cd%
> ```

I would expect that to do nothing as `%cd%` is already the current directory.

Perhaps wanting to change directory to the script directory:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

View `for /?` or `call /?` about modifiers like `dp`.